# How do i show enum value using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, enums

I have created an enum in my mode.

```
public enum Color
{
    Green,
    Black,
    Red,
    Silver,
    Yellow,
    White,
    Grey,
}
```

I used thus enum in my main class.

```
public class MotorDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Kilometers { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
 }
```

I then seed data like

```
context.MotorDetails.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, new MotorDetails()
{
   Name = "Accord",
   Make = "Honda",
   Model = "Accord",
   Year = r.Next(1980,2016).ToString(),
   Kilometers = r.Next(50000, 200000).ToString(),
   Color = (Color)r.Next(1,7),
}
```

So,in database any value b/w 1,7 is saved for color. **Which is fine.**

Now i am return this data to my view from controller

```
public List<MotorDetails> getByMake(string make, int minPrice, int maxPrice)
{
    List<MotorDetails> motor = db.MotorDetails.Where(x => x.Make == make && x.Price >= minPrice && x.Price <= maxPrice).ToList();
    return motor;
}
```

**Problem:**
It returns an integer for color to my view and hence number is showing on view.
I want to show color name for given number.

I am using angularJs and here is my code.

```
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Kilometers</th> 
        <th>Price</th>   
        <th>Color</th>           
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="m in motors">
        <td>{{m.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Make}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Model}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Year}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Kilometers}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Price}}</td>
        <td>{{m.Color}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.NET (the default json serializer for ASP.NET) has an attribute for this `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`

So

```
public class MotorDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Kilometers { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

Will serialize the Color as the string value.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this by having a similar object on the client that represents the enum on the server.

Something like:

```
vm.lookups.colors = [];
vm.lookups.colors.push({ id: 1, value: 'Green' });
vm.lookups.colors.push({ id: 2, value: 'Black' });
// etc.
```

Then in my view I will render a select and bing the ng-model of the select to the value from the server:

```
<select ng-options="color.id as color.value for color in vm.lookups.colors" 
        ng-model="m.Color" disabled>
</select>
```

Comment: That way i know but i think that is not smart way. So asked this on this forum to get smart approach.

Comment: Will you be creating these objects on the client at any point ? If so, you will need to know the enum values on the client. If not, you could just send the enum value ( not the number ) from the server to the client

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to adding the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute on your model property is to add a formatter in your WebApiConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still of interest. I solved this problem differently:

1) Load json data just as before. Serialize enums as Integers, not as strings.

2) Load list of enums as pairs of {Id, Name} from an ApiController. The Name properties are filled with language-specific strings.

3) Lookup the localized Name for each enum Id in the list by a simple javascript method call to your AngularJS controller. (Alternatively you could use a filter here, but thats up to you)

4) Hookup the $rootScope.$On('translateChangeSuccess',...) event to reload the localized enums if the language has been changed.

Let me know if this was not clear enough and/or you need a code example.